# #id child of $(this)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, selector

I apologize for the messy script and tags, I am just a beginner.  I want to select the text in the div with the class "reserveAPickupAppointmentLocation. This div is inside $(this).  $(this) is the selected entry out of many.  The line that is relevant is:

```
var location = $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentLocation, this").text();
```

This returns the location from all entries, instead of just from $(this).  How do I get only what I want?

Full jquery function:

```
   $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment").click (function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("confirm")) {
    }
    else {
        $("img").remove(".confirmAppointment");
        $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment").removeClass("confirm");
        $(this).addClass("confirm");
        $(this).append("<img src=images/confirmAppointment.png class=confirmAppointment id=roommateAppointment>");
            $(".confirmAppointment").click (function() {
                $(".confirmAppointment").unbind("click");
                var location = $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentLocation, this").text();
                alert (location);
            });
    }
   });
```

relevant php part

```
echo '<table>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

echo
'<tbody class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment">
    <tr>
            <td>'
                .$row["name"].
            '</td>
            <td>
                <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentLocation">'
                    .$row["location"].
                '</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentSubLocation">'
                    .$row["subLocation"].
                '</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentStartTime">'
                .$row["startTime"].
            '</span>    - 
            <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentEndTime">'
            .$row["endTime"].
                '</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentDate">'
                .$row["date"].
                '</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>';
}

echo '</table>
```

Comment: @lotusH updated with html...I know this is a messy way to get my data back, I had a discussion with someone earlier on this forum, but haven't had a chance to change it yet.

Comment: and thank you for making me posting that, while cleaning it up, I found the error...I had spelled location wrong 4 times (probably copied and pasted), it not works with the code from below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a second parameter to a jQuery selector as the context in which to search, you'll need to close your quotes first.

```
var location = $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentLocation", this).text();
```

**BUT**

The value of `this` in your click callback will change value, so you'll need to save it beforehand.

```
$(this).append("<img src=images/confirmAppointment.png class=confirmAppointment id=roommateAppointment>");
var self = this;
$(".confirmAppointment").click (function() {
    $(".confirmAppointment").unbind("click");
    var location = $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentLocation", self).text();
    alert (location);
});
```

Comment: This is the solution that finally worked, but I also needed to correct another typo, I had misspelled "location" several times form copying and pasting incorrectly.  I am betting if I tried the other ones, I would be more successful also.

Answer (score 1):

You just have your quotation marks wrong:

```
$(".reserveAPickupAppointmentLocaton", this).text();
```

`this` is a second argument to the jQuery function to specify the context, you had it as part of the selector. Context is an optional argument for [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: this returns my url, actually, for some reason

Comment: oops, I had inserted this wrong, it does not show up with a url, just blank like the others

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var location = $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentLocaton", $(this)).text();
```